# Pylint failing to load plugin on a mercurial precommit hook

Tags: python, mercurial, pylint, mercurial-hook

I am trying to create a mercurial pre-commit hook that runs `pylint` on the pre-commit. My project uses a virtual environment.

I have the hook set up to call `pylint` on the changed files but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/barmstrong/.virtualenvs/amp/bin/pylint", line 10, in <module>
        sys.exit(run_pylint())
      File "/home/barmstrong/.virtualenvs/amp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 20, in run_pylint
        Run(sys.argv[1:])
      File "/home/barmstrong/.virtualenvs/amp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 1583, in __init__
        linter.load_plugin_modules(plugins)
      File "/home/barmstrong/.virtualenvs/amp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 636, in load_plugin_modules
        module = modutils.load_module_from_name(modname)
      File "/home/barmstrong/.virtualenvs/amp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/modutils.py", line 202, in load_module_from_name
        return load_module_from_modpath(dotted_name.split("."), path, use_sys)
      File "/home/barmstrong/.virtualenvs/amp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astroid/modutils.py", line 244, in load_module_from_modpath
        mp_file, mp_filename, mp_desc = imp.find_module(part, path)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 297, in find_module
        raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
    ImportError: No module named 'common'
```

I believe this is due to a custom plugin in the `.pylintrc` file that it tries to load from my project directory in:

```
'/common/blah/file.py'
```

And in the `.pylintrc` it is referenced by:

```
common.blah.file
```

I try to add this to the `PYTHONPATH` running:

```
sys.path.append('path/common')
```

But the error persists. How do I solve this so it can load my plugin? (I have also tried variations of adding the common module to the `PYTHONPATH` with no success).

EDIT: If I remove the `common.blah/file.py` file from my `.pylintrc` it works, so I need to figure out how I can `import` it. I have tried adding 'common' to the `PYTHONPATH` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Where do you do the `sys.path.append('path/common')`? Have you tried actually using the PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: @lxop I do the sys.path.append at the beginning of the file after imports. I haven't tried actually adding it to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: At the beginning of which file? If it's the file that you are linting, then it won't help, as it is not actually evaluated. You'll need to set it in the PYTHONPATH env var

Comment: Could you show your complete hook?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're editing the source of pylint, then having

```
sys.path.append('path/common')
```

won't be helping at all because pylint isn't evaluating your source files. Even if it were, that would occur after it tried to load your plugin, so it would have already failed.

You'll need to add the path by setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable so that it is available to Pylint when it runs. Don't forget that the path to add is not `'path/common'` but `'path/'`, since it needs to be the path to where the `common` package lives, not the path of the package itself.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when I added a plugin to pylint via my `.pylintrc`:

```
[MASTER]

load-plugins=path.to.my.plugin
```

This worked fine on my machine but gave me the `ImportError` on CircleCI. The solution (building on @lxop's answer) was to run pylint with a custom `PYTHONPATH` on CircleCI:

```
PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) pylint
```

Answer (score -2):

Apparently it's a dependency that you can install in order to resolve your problem, you can find the module [here](https://pypi.org/project/common/)

Comment: No, I am pretty sure it is trying to load my custom plugin stored in 'common/pylint/plugin.py' and it cannot find it.